# Referencing 5 random URL`s from a file of 50 URL`s and automatically opening all 5 in a browser. Repeated every 5 mins

Tags: powershell, variables, filepath, start-process

**Overview:**
Have around 50 websites in work, all URL`s have been added to a CSV file. We want a selection of 5 random sites to pop up in a web browser every 5 minutes and using a browser tab rotator to rotate through all 5 web pages. Browser closes, then another random 5 web sites from the CSV open etc.

**Problem:**
Apologies for the noob question, I am extremely new to programming and Powershell, I cannot find a way to reference $URL1 or $URL2 etc at the end of the `-FilePath Firefox -ArgumentList` statement.

**Code:**

```
$importPath = "C:\URLlist.csv" 
$list = Import-Csv -Path $importPath
$URL1 = Get-Random -InputObject $list
$URL2 = Get-Random -InputObject $list ...
$URL5 = Get-Random -InputObject $list
Start-Process -FilePath Firefox -ArgumentList ????
```

Assuming you geniuses will know of a more efficient way, so any advice or direction greatly appreciated.

Many thanks

Charlie

Comment: you pro'ly cannot rotate thru the tabs unless you install & use something like selenium OR switch to using IE & the IE Com interface.///// `Get-Random` has a `-Count` parameter that will give you 5 unique items from the list.

Comment: `$urls = Get-Random -Count 5 -InputObject $list; Start-Process -FilePath Firefox -ArgumentList $urls` doesn't work?